# How can one improve performance in a neural network?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance, neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm

I am implementing a basic NeuroEvolution program. The Data Set I am attempting is the "Cover Type" data set. This set has 15,120 records with 56 inputs (numerical data on patches of forest land) and 1 output (the cover type). As recommended, I am using 150 hidden neurons. The fitness function attempts to iterate through all 15,120 records to calculate an error, and use that error to calculate the fitness. The method is shown below.

```
double getFitness() {
    double error = 0.0;

    // for every record in the dataset.
    for (int record = 0; record < targets.size(); record++) {
        // evaluate output vector for this record of inputs.
        vector<double> outputs = eval(inputs[record]);

        // for every value in those records.
        for (int value = 0; value < outputs.size(); value++) {
            // add to error the difference.
            error += abs(outputs[value] - targets[record][value]);
        }
    }

    return 1 - (error / targets.size());
}
```

"inputs" and "targets" are 2-D vectors read-in from the CSV file. The entire program uses ~40 MB of memory at run-time. That is not a problem. The program mutates off of a parent network, both are evaluated for fitness, and the most fit is kept to be mutated-upon. In the entire process, the getFitness() function is taking the most time. The program is written in Visual Studio 2017 (on a 2.6GHz i7) in Windows 10.

It took ~7 minutes to evaluate ONE network's fitness, using 21% of CPU. Smaller problems have required hundreds of thousands.

What methods are available to get that number down?

Comment: The first thing to check is do you have optimization turned on? Visual C++'s standard library is especially slow in debug mode. Make sure you're doing a release mode build.

Comment: You should learn about [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) if possible since it is much faster than a genetic algorithm. I would recommend [this](https://youtu.be/aircAruvnKk) video series since it explains the basics without too much calculus.

Comment: Do you have a GPU available? If you do and is NVIDIA one then use CUDA to optimize it, if it is AMD then use OpenCL.

Comment: I will try optimizing visual studio. Learning isn't an option; I'm doing something with the net's that isn't possible with learning (I've tried). And yes, I have a GPU available.

Comment: Can you post `eval`? Is `eval` inlined into `getFitness`? If so, its time is attributed to `getFitness` by the Visual Studio profiler. Preallocating the `outputs` vector and reusing it may save some time. I am not sure how to set this in Visual Studio, but compilers do a better job of optimizing if you tell them to optimize for a particular CPU, because then they can use instructions that are not found on every CPU

Answer (score 0):

The program, implemented making (apparently) significant use of vectors, cannot be directly offloaded to a GPU using OpenCL or CUDA without significant modifications. This makes OpenMP the most viable option. As few as 2 lines of code can be added to "go parallel." In addition, Visual Studio must be set to use OpenMP (Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support).

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <numeric>

// libraries, variables, functions, etc...

double getFitness() {
    double err = 0.0;

    vector<double> error;
    error.resize(inputs.size());

    // for every record in the dataset.
#pragma omp parallel for    
    for (int record = 0; record < targets.size(); record++) {
        // evaluate output vector for this record of inputs.
        vector<double> outputs = eval(inputs[record]);

        // for every value in those records.
        for (int value = 0; value < outputs.size(); value++) {
            // add to error the difference.
            error[record] = abs(outputs[value] - targets[record][value]);
        }
    }

    err = accumulate(error.begin(), error.end(), 0);

    return 1 - (err / targets.size());
}
```

In the above code, OMP should create a thread for each of the records. However, unless you run this on a cloud instance, it will eat your CPU. Expect a ~4x improvement on a quad-core CPU.